# Angular: Trying to return JSON data is causing a error in my service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to return JSON data is causing a error in my service. Here is the code...looks simple enough!

```
var app = angular.module('easyjet', []);

app.service('FlightsService', function($http) {

    return {
        'selectedResult': null,
        'resultsData': $http.get('http://ejtestbed.herokuapp.com/flights')
    };

});

app.controller('ResultsController', function($scope, FlightsService) {

    // Default sort setting
    $scope.order = "flightNumber.number";

    // Using service
    $scope.flights = FlightsService;
});

app.controller('DetailedFlightController', function($scope, FlightsService) {

    // Using service
    $scope.flights = FlightsService;

});
```

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the error??

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/filter/notarray?p0=%7B%22$$state%22:%7B%22status%22:-1%7D%7D

Comment: the second error is : Error: filter:notarray
Not an array

Comment: @Rob The problem is the array its looking for is not being loaded in 'resultsData' in my code

Comment: `$http.get()` returns a promise. Are you using this promise to wait for the server to respond before trying to use the data?

Comment: @SunilD. I'm new to JavaScript and especially Angular...this is my 1st go at it. What is promise and how do I use it in this example? Thanks

Comment: Http requests are asynchronous actions, meaning that they will finish at some point in time after beeing called, succesfully or not. Because data can be returned at some point in time `$http.get` will return a `$promise`. Basically saying i will return something at some point. You have 2 callback possibilities 1.success 2.error. `$promise.then(function(data){//success;},function(){//err;})`. As for the usage @Rob provided a really good fiddle for your case, namely `FlightsService.resultsData().then(function(response) {//do smth wih your data});`

Answer (score 1):

Your resultsData property needs to return a function, not an $http request:

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/yh26oey6/

```
 return {
  'selectedResult': null,
  'resultsData': function() {
    return $http.get('https://api.zippopotam.us/us/90210');
  }
```

And, without seeing how you're calling the service, there could be other issues also.

Comment: Your controller is not calling the resultsData function, it's just referencing the service. Take a look at the fiddle link in my answer to get a better idea of how this could work.